# Array search for 1s and 0s

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I want to traverse a logic vector of 32 bits and find the indices which have value of 1 and 0 and store them in two separate arrays.

I will know through a input which will tell number of ones in the array.

The indices array will be two dimensional.

Also I want this to be implemented using combo logic and synthesizable.

I am not able to think of any logic without latch being inferred.

```
logic [31:0] data ; // Array to be traversed
logic [31:0] [ONES_NUM-1:0]    one_index;// One's indices in array
logic [31:0] [32-ONES_NUM-1:0]   zero_index;//Zeros indices in array

always @(*)
   while(j < ONES_NUM)
      while ( i < 32)
      if(data[i]==1) begin
         one_index[j][31:0] = i;
         j++;
         i++;
         end
      else
         i++; //Here prob is no else statement so latch inferred.
```

Similar always@(*) for zero index as well.

Also I have doubts whether while loop is synthesizable.

Kindly help with the logic.

Comment: "and **store** them..." You can not store data unless you have a clock. Whatever you do: without clock you get latches. You should read up a bit more how HDL coding works as you write HDL as it it is C-code.

Comment: When the `@*` is triggered, `i`,`j`,`one_index`,etc. have unknown value that will be evaluated and modified. You need to initialize them every time within the always block. `while` loops are not synthesize; `for` loops that static unroll can synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

```
logic [31:0] data ;
   logic  [31:0][(ONES_NUM-1):0] one_index; // One's indices in array
   logic  [31:0][(32-ONES_NUM-1):0] zero_index; // Zeros indices in array
   bit clk;
   int j,k;
   always@(posedge clk)
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
      begin
        if(data[i]==1)
          begin
            one_index[j]=i;
            j++;
          end
        else
          begin
            zero_index[k]=i;
            k++;
          end
      end
```

You have to use a clock to avoid latches.

you can refer to this link https://www.edaplayground.com/x/kZ6 for better understanding.